# setTimeout with changing timeout value

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, settimeout

I'm working on some timeout in jQuery but I got a problem with my timeout value.
So, I got an array of value (Ex : ["2490", "4200"]), and I want my timeout to print the value of the array after 2490ms, then go back to 0 and finaly print the next value of the array after 4200ms. But it never go back to 0

Actualy, this is the jQuery code :

```
var array = ['2490', '4200'];
var mytimeout;

for (var i = 0; i < array.length; ++i)
{
    doTimeout(i);
    clearTimeout(mytimeout);
}

function doTimeout(i) {
    mytimeout = setTimeout(function() {
       $('#text').append(array[i]);
    }, array[i]);
}
```

**JSFIDDLE** : https://jsfiddle.net/2aftscou/

So everything seems to work except the fact that I want my timer to be reinitialize at 0 when it ends (that's why I've used *clearTimeout*(), but it doesn't work in this case).

I really don't know what to do

Comment: As `timer` is cleared, callback will not be called..

Comment: Is this the desired behavior? https://jsfiddle.net/Lbjfafpz/

Comment: Yes it is, thanks dude.

Comment: Note: I think `setTimeout()` only executes once in any case, `clearTimeout()` is only needed if you want to cancel the one timeout before it happens.  `setInterval()` is repeating.

Comment: @ebyrob You're right, thanks for the correction

Comment: As a side note, take into account that defining functions inside loops is discouraged as it leads to this type of problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your current implementation is clearing the timeout right away. You can chain the timeouts together with something like this

```js
var array = ['2490', '4200'];
var mytimeout;

function doTimeout(i) {
  mytimeout = setTimeout(function() {
    $('#text').append(array[i]);
    if (i <= array.length)
      doTimeout(i + 1);
  }, array[i]);
}

doTimeout(0);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="text">

</p>
```

Comment: That worked, thanks man I'm not used to Javascript to be honnest ^^

Answer (score 1):

This will not work. Your timeout will be killed after start. You have to start new timeout after old timeout will be executed.

Something like this

```
function doTimeout(i) {
    mytimeout = setTimeout(function() {

    $('#text').append(array[i]);
    i++;
if (i<array.length) {
doTimeout(i)
 }

   }
}
```